# Correct indexing for random look-ups between two mysql table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two MySQL tables, named `stockin` and `stockout`. Now I would like to check two table for an unique column named serialno to find stock-in hand rows. I have tried 4 select query line to random look-ups between two table. But, Every query taking too much time to execute. Can you check table indexes of tables for any wrong issues? If you have any correction or suggestion, i will appreciate.

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM stockin\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: stockin_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 14657
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: shiptype
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: shiptype
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 18
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: userid
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: userid
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 22
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: uom
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: uom
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 10
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: warehouseid
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: warehouse_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 6
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: project_id_for_stockin
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: project_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 2
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 7. row ***************************
        Table: stockin
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: cus_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: cus_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 2
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM stockout\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: stockout_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 19654
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: eng_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: eng_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 5
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 3. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: project_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: project_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 9
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 4. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: warehouseid
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: warehouseid
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 47
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: response_type_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: response_type_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 5
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: cus_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: cus_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 1
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 7. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: employee_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: employee_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 19
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 8. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: userid
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: userid
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 1
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
*************************** 9. row ***************************
        Table: stockout
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: uom
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: uom
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 11
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: YES
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the random look-ups between two table to add index which unique columns are in random checking. I have added column in index like following code, and immediately. I was amazed with the results execution time. That query was taking more than 3.30 minutes, when i added index it takes only `0.03` seconds.

```
CREATE INDEX columnname ON tablename(columnname)
```